# TFS: Automated publish a folder to Azure website

Tags: azure, tfs, msbuild

I am trying to create automated build to publish a folder with files onto Azure web-site. And I cannot accomplish this.

I am NOT publishing a solution (.sln), but rather a folder with files. I am using VS2013 and Visual Studio Online.

I have experience with TFS web publishing, so I published solutions many times.

So, what I did so far:

1. Created an MSBuild build.xml file that just copies files from the folder to the output.
2. Created a build definition based on AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml
3. Specified build.xml in my build definition, Process tab, in "Solution to build" parameter:
   [image]

If I build my project, it is correctly built, files are copied to the output, etc (I can verify it by opening drop location, all files are there).

Then, I:

4. Created a web-site in Azure, linked it to my TFS subscription.
5. Downloaded a publish profile (.PublishSettings from a web-site).
6. Created a Web publish profile (.pubxml) in Visual Studio based on .PublishSettings file).
7. Specified Web Deploy Publish Profile and Deployment Settings Name:

[image]

But now I am getting an error during build:

Exception Message: Please specify a Visual Studio Solution (.sln) to build. (type BuildFromSolutionException)

So it asks me for a Visual Studio solution, but earlier it worked perfectly with MSBuild file (after step 3).

I tried to rename my .xml to .sln (probably it is not what I should have done), and build now says "There was no Windows Azure project (.ccproj) detected in the solution. Continuous delivery to an Azure Cloud Service requires an Azure project. (type CCProjNotFoundException)"

If I don't specify "Deployment Settings Name", build completes without errors, but again no publishing to Azure.

So, the question is, how to publish a custom MSBuild build, without a solution, onto Azure? Is TFS continuous Azure publishing for Solutions only? I expect it to be agile, like I published folders from Local Git to Web-site without any hassle.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few confused ideas in your question. Fits, there is no relationship between and automated build and Git. You are using Team Foundation Build to run the workflow of deployment. It is the workflow that is not working for you. In effect the build and deployment script. In fact the script you are using works with both Git and TFVC so that is not the issue.

That specific script is designed specifically for building an azure project that is then continuously delivers to Azure and you likley can't use it as you are. You can however create another script and use that. I would suggest you try instead to use the Default build script and use a powershell script within the build to collect the files and then push them to Azure.

If you want to go a little more advanced you could create a copy of the default and make one that does not require MSBuild at all.